# Footer not on first page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I have a footer file which is rendered on every page (with the numerotation).

I'd like it not to be rendered on the first page. Do you have an idea ?

This is my code:

```
<html><head><script>
function subst() {
  var vars={};
  var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
  for(var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}
  var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
  for(var i in x) {
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
    for(var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
  }
}
</script></head><body style="border:0; margin: 0;" onload="subst()">
<table style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; width: 100%">
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left"><font face="Century Gothic">
      Page <span class="page"></span> sur <span class="topage"></span>
   </font> </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you detail any way we can identify if it's the first page or not?

Comment: how are you rendering your footer?

Comment: @Rich Peck : When <span class="page"> == 1, we are on the first page. So it may be possible to implement an if condition, but I don't know what the syntax is in this context :/

Comment: @Mandeep : I have this <meta name="pdfkit-footer_html" content="\footer.html.erb"/>. But I think the solution can be directly implemented in the footer with the right syntax

Comment: @Ananas you just want to render your footer so why not use it in a layout?

Comment: @Mandeep I'm working with PDFKIT, and it seemed to be a conveniant solution. I think a different question could be how to implement an if condition in a script like that ?

Comment: @Ananas okay so you are using `<span class="page"> == 1`  to show home page right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59573/discussion-between-mandeep-and-ananas).

Answer (score 0):

use this js in your script....first store page value in var and then use it to remove the footer.

**your html code..set the page value either by ruby/js(any way you prefer)**

```
<p id="page_value" data-value="<%= @page.value %>"></p>
```

**after setting ,use it to remove the footer**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () { 
       var value= $("#page_value").data("value");
       if (value==1){
        $('#footer').remove()
          }
       }//if ends
    </script>
```

..hope it helps...

Comment: nope, doesn't work like that. I don't have any reference to the footer in my view. I have a footer.html.erb file which is always rendered ^^

Comment: @Ananas...so u have a layout rendering _footer.html.erb..correct??if this is the case..use the condition in layout file and still it will work...

Comment: In fact my file is "footer.html". The erb extension is useless here. So it's not a layout but an html file rendered as a footer.

Comment: @Ananas...i have updated my answer...can u give it a try

Comment: where should I put the <p></p> code ? Because I don't think the variable @ page can be recognized in my code above